# NHibernate IQueryable properties

Tags: nhibernate, iqueryable

i have some code:

```
public class Hippo
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name {get;set;}
}
public class Zoo
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IQueryable<Hippo> Hippos { get; set; } 
}
```

Can I create Hippos as this in NHibernate (or fluent nhibernate)?
Or can I pass a Session to this object?

How I can do it? (with help of NHibernage.Linq or NHibernate.CollectionQuery?)

My target is like this:

```
_session.Query<Zoo>().Where(e => e.Hippos.Where(h=>h.Name=="Bobby").Any())
```

Comment: for the query posted there is nothing special needed, just `IList<Hippo> Hippos { get; protected set; }`

Comment: I know about IList, but by default, when I call this property, it returns all Hippos from from a data base, but I need the QUERY. My zoo has 100500 hippos, and I want to use pages in ZooForm

Comment: Then you would have `_session.Query<Zoo>().SelectMany(e => e.Hippos).Where(h => h.Name=="Bobby").Skip(pageindex * pagesize).Take(pagesize).OrderBy(h => h.Id).ToList<Hippo>()` for each page hence no need for IQueryable<Hippo>

Comment: yes, but for every small pages SQL will return ALL records even if I need one page. ALL records(100500) for one page(50), in every http request from users...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define queries through `session.Query<>` it looks like the collection is accessed but it is not. It is just referenced in the resulting Expression which is translated to sql. So querying pages will forward the limiting to the database so only a few records are fetched. For example the following query will only return 50 hippos:

```
const int pagesize = 50;
_session.Query<Zoo>()
    .SelectMany(e => e.Hippos)
        .Where(h => h.Name=="Bobby")
    .Skip(pageindex * pagesize).Take(pagesize)
    .OrderBy(h => h.Id)
    .ToList<Hippo>();
```

Do not confuse with when you query the collection like `someZoo.Hippos.Where(h=>h.Name=="Bobby").ToList()`. This will trigger lazyloading and fetch all the hippos for the zoo. So collections on the DomainModel holding a possibly large amount of items is a bad idea to start with. Someone will use it in code and it will not crash when developing with small datasets. Better only use the backreference `somehippo.ContainingZoo` if possible and query

```
const int pagesize = 50;
_session.Query<Hippo>()
    .Where(h => h.Name=="Bobby")
    .Skip(pageindex * pagesize).Take(pagesize)
    .OrderBy(h => h.Id)
    .ToList<Hippo>();
```

**Update:**

experimental code for queryable properties. Not pretty but usable

```
class ZooMap : ClassMap<Zoo>
{
    public ZooMap()
    {
        ...

        Map(x => x.Hippos)
            .CustomType<QueryableHipposUserType>()
            .Formula("1")
            .ReadOnly();
    }
}

class QueryableHipposUserType : ICompositeUserType
{
    public object Assemble(object cached, ISessionImplementor session, object owner)
    {
        return cached;
    }

    public object DeepCopy(object value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object Disassemble(object value, ISessionImplementor session)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object x)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public object GetPropertyValue(object component, int property)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public bool IsMutable
    {
        get { return false; ; }
    }

    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader dr, string[] names, ISessionImplementor session, object owner)
    {
        var zooId = ((Zoo)owner).Id;
        return ((NHibernate.ISession)session).Query<Hippo>().Where(hippo => hippo.ContainingZoo.Id == zooId);
    }

    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index, bool[] settable, ISessionImplementor session)
    {
    }

    public string[] PropertyNames
    {
        get { return new string[0]; }
    }

    public IType[] PropertyTypes
    {
        get { return new IType[]{ NHibernateUtil.Int32 }; }
    }

    public object Replace(object original, object target, ISessionImplementor session, object owner)
    {
        return original;
    }

    public Type ReturnedClass
    {
        get { return typeof(IQueryable<Hippo>); }
    }

    public void SetPropertyValue(object component, int property, object value)
    {
    }
}

var someZoo = session.Get<Zoo>(zooId);
var theHappyHippos = someZoo.Hippos.Where(h => h.Name=="Bobby").ToList();
```

Comment: I understand id. I know how works _session.Query<Hippo>().
And in my question I ask, HOW I CAN MAKE THIS "t looks like the collection is accessed but it is not. It is just referenced in the resulting Expression which is translated to sql." WITH NAVIGATION PROPERTY. and I know, by default NHibernate get all records from DB (into navigation property)

Comment: Sorry for my English, maybe you are not understand my question?

Comment: session management would be awkward with a simple property so the best i can think of would be: `public IQueryable<Hippo> Hippos(ISession session) { return session.Query<Hippo>().Where(h => h.ContainingZoo.Id == this.Id); }`. Mind you the session holds the connection, transaction and cache so using another session will mess things up probably.

Comment: in MVC pattern (in my application) Model do not now about session (or Context from Entity Framework), only about IQueryable properties:( therefore I cannot pass session from client-side (Model), only with IQueryable collection from session...

Comment: i would strongly discourage from it but you could implement `ICompositeUserType` to set the IQueryable when dehydrating the object. It would result in stale IQueryables when the session is closed. I can post some code if needed

Comment: if not difficult. I am interested to take a look:) problems "when the session is closed" - it is small problem (as solution, we can use Disposable interface

Comment: didn't have a lot of time recently ... but here goes